# Read data from text file and use that data to get the dictionary data with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newer for a python language. I want to be read the data from the text file(multiple lines in the text file), Then use the data that read from the text file to execute with the dictionary function.

```
def readCmd():
    f = open('cmd.txt', "r")
    line = f.readline()
    for line in f:

        print (line)
        time.sleep(1)
        return str(line)

    f.close()

def zero():
    print( "Hi 0")

def one():
    print( "Test 1")

def two():
    print( "end 2")

def num_to_func_to_str(argument):
    switcher = {
        "Hi": zero,
        "test": one,
        "end": two,
    }
    print(switcher.get(argument,"Please enter only 'Hi', 'test' and 'end'"))

def main():
    #readCmd()
    while 1 :
        time.sleep(0.5)
        num_to_func_to_str(readCmd())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above code is the code that I tried. it showed just the second line and not go to the dictionary(switcher) condition. This code is skipped to `print(switcher.get(argument,"Please enter only 'Hi', 'test' and 'end'"))`

The data in text file as below.

```
start
Hi 
test
Hi 
test
Hi 
test
Hi 
test
Hi 
test
Hi 
test
end
```

Can anyone suggest to me for the how to solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved this issue. I have to read that data in a text file and store that data in the list type

```
def zero():
    print ("called function 1")

def one():
    print ("called function 2")

def two():
    print ("called function 3")

tokenDict = {
    "cat":zero,
    "dog":one,
    "bear":two
    }

lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("cmd.txt")]

for line in lineList:
    time.sleep(1)
    # lookup the function to call for each line
    functionToCall = tokenDict[line]
    # and call it
    functionToCall()
```

Refer from[1]: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65126-dictionary-of-methodsfunctions/
Refer from[2]: https://qiita.com/visualskyrim/items/1922429a07ca5f974467

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to do it this way; you could open it once, and each time through your loop read 1 line & process it.

Answer (score 0):

`readCmd` returns after opening the file & reading the first line every time it is called.  Since that first line is `start`, it doesn't match anything in `switcher`.

Comment: Yes, that right for now. How I can do that to read through the text file?